# Create a dictionary from dataframe column which has more than one value in its cell

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dataframe like this,

[image]

I want to create a dictionary from this to remap a column in another data frame ( if you look at 330th row it has 524 and 545. I want to assign a single value(330) in another dataframe)

So i used this code to create a dictorionary.

```
di = new2.T.to_dict('list')
```

But the dictionary i get is this,

```html
{0: ['-1'],
 1: ['187'],
 2: ['212'],
 3: ['30'],
 4: ['209'],
 5: ['213'],
 6: ['214'],
 7: ['238'],
 8: ['544'],
 9: ['557'],
 10: ['317'],
 11: ['516'],
 12: ['571'],
 13: ['184, 549'],
 14: ['64'],
 15: ['43'],
 16: ['584'],
 17: ['185'],
 18: ['190'],
 19: ['218'],
 20: ['174'],
 21: ['550'],
 22: ['138'],
 23: ['1'],
 24: ['311'],
 25: ['576'],
 26: ['500'],
 27: ['208, 241'],
 28: ['16'],
 29: ['327'],
 30: ['3, 34, 50'],
 31: ['332'],
 32: ['520'],
 33: ['491'],
 34: ['535'],
 35: ['523'],
 36: ['119'],
 37: ['482'],
 38: ['574'],
 39: ['165'],
 40: ['370'],
 41: ['51, 62, 73, 87, 101, 120, 199, 240, 304, 360, 506'],
```

And when i invert it using this code,

```
{value: key for key, values in di.items() for value in values}
```

It becomes this,

```js
{'-1': 0,
 '187': 1,
 '212': 2,
 '30': 3,
 '209': 4,
 '213': 5,
 '214': 6,
 '238': 7,
 '544': 8,
 '557': 9,
 '317': 10,
 '516': 11,
 '571': 12,
 '184, 549': 13,
 '64': 14,
 '43': 15,
 '584': 16,
 '185': 17,
 '190': 18,
 '218': 19,
 '174': 20,
 '550': 21,
 '138': 22,
 '1': 23,
 '311': 24,
 '576': 25,
 '500': 26,
 '208, 241': 27,
 '16': 28,
 '327': 29,
 '3, 34, 50': 30,
 '332': 31,
 '520': 32,
 '491': 33,
 '535': 34,
 '523': 35,
 '119': 36,
 '482': 37,
 '574': 38,
 '165': 39,
 '370': 40,
 '51, 62, 73, 87, 101, 120, 199, 240, 304, 360, 506': 41,
 '525': 42,
```

But I want is to map them individually such as,

```
184: 13,
549: 13,
```

instead of this,

```
'184, 549': 13,
```

and use .map() function to map it using the dictionary

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This looks like an [XY Problem](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) - what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to give a single value to the two or more values in a data frame column. If you take a look at the dataframe. the cell value has 234,234 together (values can be two or more). I want to assign a single value to both and use that mapping to replace values in a different dataframe that has those values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have string inside a list, just split the string:

```
di = {
    27: ['208, 241'],
    28: ['16'],
    29: ['327'],
    30: ['3, 34, 50'],
    31: ['332'],
    32: ['520'],
    33: ['491']
}

result = {value: key for key, values in di.items() for value in values[0].split(', ')}
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
{'208': 27, '241': 27, '16': 28, '327': 29, '3': 30, '34': 30, '50': 30, '332': 31, '520': 32, '491': 33}
```

Note that I used a small fraction of `di` as an example, this can be applied to the whole dictionary.

Comment: Hey this works <3 ! but when i use new4['cluster-new']= df_clustering_dupliacteRemove['cluster'].map(result)  to appl the mapping it returns nan values. the cluster collumn has int values, but the map key values are string. any ideas ?

Comment: I used this to convert it {int(key):result[key] for key in result}